# Assign multiple function outputs to a vector using indexing in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, vector

I have a simple MATLAB function outputting multiple variables:

```
function [a,b] = MultipleOutputs()
a = 6;
b = 8;
end
```

I want to assign the two output variables to 2 certain elements in an existing vector:

```
x = ones(1,4);
x(2:3) = MultipleOutputs()
```

However, this gives me:

```
x =

     1     6     6     1
```

Instead of:

```
x =

     1     6     8     1
```

I have had this problem in multiple cases, was never able to find the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 choices:

Concatenate the vectors after outputting them separately

```
[a,b] = MultipleOutputs();
x = ones(1,4);
x(2:3) = [a,b];
```

concatenate the vectors before outputting them

```
function a = MultipleOutputs()
    a(1) = 6;
    a(2) = 8;
end

x(2:3) = MultipleOutputs();
```

Comment: Third alternative, cell array: `x=num2cell(ones(1,4));[x{2:3}]=MultipleOutputs();`, but it is likely that returning a vector is the best choice.

Answer (score 2):

when you run `MultipleOutputs()` like that in another function, it only outputs only the first element, which in this case is `a`.

So eventually your statement `x(2:3) = MultipleOutputs()` is equivalent to `x(2:3) = 6`.

A simple fix would be to extract all the elements:

```
[a,b] = MultipleOutputs();
x(2:3) = [a b];
```